# Android databinding src ImageView in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I am showing a list of include items

```
<include
        layout="@layout/item_tags"
         android:title='@{"text"}'
         android:image='@{"@drawable/ic_write_item.xml"}'/>
```

this layout contains

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="title"
            type="java.lang.String" />

        <variable
            name="image"
            type="java.lang.String" />
    </data>
```

...

```
  <ImageView...
                    android:src="@{image}"/>

                <TextView...
                    android:text="@{title}" />
```

also created `myDatabindingAdapter`

```
object DataBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setImageUri(view: ImageView, imageUri: Uri) {
        view.setImageURI(imageUri)
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setImageDrawable(view: ImageView, drawable: Drawable) {
        view.setImageDrawable(drawable)
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setImageResource(imageView: ImageView, resource: Int) {
        imageView.setImageResource(resource)
    }
}
```

and initialized in fragment this way

```
 val binding: FragmentTagsBinding =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_tags, container,false)

        return binding.root
```

When I run it I receive the following error.

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: @drawable/ic_write_item.xml (No such
>   file or directory) W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
>   @drawable/ic_write_item.xml

Is it a problem with the adapter? should I send the resource `id` instead of the file name?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: android:image='@{"@drawable/ic_write_item.xml"}' won't work because you pass it as a String but when you write "@{@drawable/ic_write_item}" it gets resolved by databinding as a Drawable.

Comment: I tried it and I get the following error 
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was declaring a variable in `XML` as `String` instead of  `type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable"`

also see @Janosch answer `@{@drawable/ic_write_item}` instead of `@{"@drawable/ic_write_item.xml"}`

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this? Your solution is correct but it only solves half the problem. I am facing the same issue but as far as I have figured, the problem does not lie in passing the resource, it is in setting the resource. If you remove `android:src="@{image}"`, then the code will build, but when you put it back it will fail, as it is failing for me. Please let me know of your outcome. Thanks!

Comment: Hi again, Your answer works when we use `android:src="@{image}"`, but I was using AppCompatImageView and setting `app:srcCompat="@{image}"` when it was throwing error.

Comment: I haven't tried before with AppCompactImageView but maybe this can help you
https://cameronstonerblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/18/imageview-vs-appcompatimageview/ have you tried changing your bindingAdapter? what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Android:src not gets String value. It needs a resource id (int). Additionally you can take a look at that for passing data to included layout https://medium.com/@elia.maracani/android-data-binding-passing-a-variable-to-an-include-d-layout-3567099b58f

Comment: Thanks, my mistake to pass the string. I have followed this article and it's working with the rest of variables but not with src attribute. I think @Janosch answer is correct but maybe kotlin problem?